# How to write a function named isMeera that returns 1 if its array argument is a Meera array. Otherwise, it returns 0

Tags: java, c#, arrays

A Meera array is defined to be an array that contains at least one odd number and  begins and ends with the same number of even numbers.

So {4, 8, 6, 3, 2, 9, 8,11, 8, 13, 12, 12, 6} is a Meera array because it begins with three even numbers and ends with three even numbers and it contains at least one odd number.
The array {2, 4, 6, 8, 6} is not a Meera array because it does not contain an odd number.
The array {2, 8, 7, 10, -4, 6} is not a Meera array because it begins with two even numbers but ends with three even numbers.
Here is my try but could not get the result. Please help me ! Thank in advance!

```
    public static int isMeera(int [] a){
boolean hasOdd = false;
int firstEven = 0;
int lastEven = 0;
boolean firstCountEnd = false;
boolean lastCountEnd = false;
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    if (a[i]%2 == 1)
            {
                hasOdd = true;
                break;
            }
}
for (int j = 0; j<a.length; j++){

    if(a[(a.length - 1) - j] % 2 == 1){
        firstCountEnd = true;
        if ((!firstCountEnd) && (a[j]%2==0)){
            firstEven ++;
        }
    }
      if(a[(a.length - 1) - j] % 2 == 1){
        lastCountEnd = true;
        if ((!lastCountEnd) && (a[j]%2==0)){
            lastEven ++;
        }
    }
}
if (hasOdd && firstEven == lastEven)
    return 1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be straight forward, to be honest. If you need a tutorial on Java, Stack Overflow is not the place for you.

Comment: This is a copied and pasted homework problem with zero effort

Comment: First try to do something by yourself. Then ask if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works successfully !

```
public static int isMeera(int [] a){
boolean hasOdd = false;
int firstEven = 0;
int lastEven = 0;
boolean firstCountEnd = false;
boolean lastCountEnd = false;
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    if (a[i]%2 == 1)
            {
                hasOdd = true;
                break;
            }
}
if (!hasOdd)
    return 0;

for (int j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
    if(a[j]%2==1)
        firstCountEnd=true;
    if(!firstCountEnd && a[j]%2==0)
        firstEven++;
    if(a[(a.length-1)-j]%2==1)
        lastCountEnd=true;
    if(!lastCountEnd && a[(a.length-1)-j]%2==0)
        lastEven++;
}
//System.out.println(firstEven +" " +lastEven);
if (hasOdd && firstEven == lastEven)

    return 1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have got the correct solution for it. Make that question Open .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working answer!

```
    public static bool IsMirra(int[] l1)
    {
        return((l1.Select(l=>l%(1<<1)==(1>>1)?'l':'1').TakeWhile(l=>(l^(((1<<1)+(1<<(1^1))<<((1<<1)<<1))+(1<<(1^1))))!=(l^l)).Count()-l1.Select(l=>l%(1<<1)==(1>>1)?'l':'1').Reverse().TakeWhile(l=>(l^(((1<<1)+(1<<(1^1))<<((1<<1)<<1))+(1<<(1^1))))!=(l^l)).Count())==(1^1))&&(l1.Select(l=>l%(1<<1)==(1>>1)?'l':'1').Any(l=>(l^(((1<<1)+(1<<(1^1))<<((1<<1)<<1))+(1<<(1^1))))==(l^l)));
    }
```

If you actually want a legible answer as opposed to just a functional one, I'd be happy to help once you put in the effort and take a stab at it yourself.

### Edit

Okay, since you actually showed some effort and posted what you had, here are some tips:

1. Check if there's at least one odd number in the array.
2. Add a piece of code that takes your array and counts how many even numbers the array begins with.  Store that as a variable.
3. Now add a piece of code that takes your array and counts how many even numbers the array ends with. Store that as a variable.

I think your code for #1 works - it looks okay.  I would recommend getting rid of the second loop you have and breaking it into two - one starting at the beginning of the array and counting forwards, one starting at the end and counting backwards.  You can actually skip both of these loops if there is no odd number because you already know it's not a "mirra" array.

There are more optimizations you could do to reduce the number of elements of the array you need to access, but for now I'd focus on writing a legible, correct solution and not necessarily the most optimized solution possible.

By the way, all of that is essentially what my very obfuscated code did - it counted the number of leading even numbers of the array, it counted the number of leading even numbers of a reversed copy of the array (i.e. the number of terminal even numbers), and it checked for the existence of at least one odd number.

Comment: Oh good, can we turn this question like the folks at [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Homework-Question-How-do-I-write-a-program-that-produces-the-following-output-1)?

Comment: Please try to solve the problem without using built in method. Thanks for replying.